# jQuery Ajax execute function variable in ajax parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I have no idea what happen to do action inside jQuery ajax.

Here's simple code. 
This code call ddd function when executing jquery ajax.

```
       
    
    
    
    
        function ddd()
        {
            alert('alert event')
        }

        var param = {
            data: ddd
        }

        $.ajax({
            data: param
        })
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? which will let you to get your  answer.

Comment: Please provide specific question and more easy to understand.

Comment: @User6667769, @ Rafraf dela Cruz hi. I inserted javascript function such as  ddd() into variable param. and I executed $.ajax with data parameter then ajax called ddd() function before submitted ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function using ajax like that

```
 var param = {
            data: ddd
        }

 $.ajax({

     type: "POST",
     url: " your url",
     data: param


    success: function(){
        ddd();
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
function ddd()
{
//do something;
}
```

Comment: I mean that I would like to know why contained function variable ddd is executed from jQuery ajax. because It was just a contained variable. I thought jQuery ajax attempt to something by ajax data property